# Binary tree insertion method causes stack overflow

Tags: c++, struct, tree

## The problem

I'm having some doubts with my insertion method in C++, it causes a stack overflow.

## Compiled with g++ on Windows

g++ -Wall -O2 Tree.cpp -o Tree

## Output

0 [unknown (0x2B70)] Tree 10496 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to Tree.exe.stackdump

## Code

```
# include < iostream >

using namespace std;

struct Node{

    int val;
    Node *left, *right;

};

Node* Insert(Node *node, int val)
{

    if(node == NULL)
    {
        node = new Node;
        node->val = val;
        node->right = node->left = NULL;
    }   

if(node->val > val)
    node->left = Insert(node->left, val);
else
    node->right = Insert(node->right, val);

return node;

}

int main()
{

Node *root = NULL; // New tree

root = Insert(root, 5);
root = Insert(root, 19);
root = Insert(root, 1);
root = Insert(root, 32);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: looks like infinite recursion to me

Comment: This is because `return node` should be added to the `if` for the base case.

Comment: Yes it was a infinite recursion hehe, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to stop recursion when it reached to `NULL`.

Try this:

```
Node* Insert(Node *node, int val)
{

    if(node == NULL)
    {
        node = new Node;
        node->val = val;
        node->right = node->left = NULL;
    }

    else if(node->val > val) // add "else" here
        node->left = Insert(node->left, val);
    else
        node->right = Insert(node->right, val);

    return node;

}
```

Comment: Wow, Now it works, I'm new in recursion :), Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
The problem in your function is, you are trying to access null memory. 
Please check my comments here

/* You are checking for node == null, which is correct. */
if(node == NULL)
    {
        node = new Node;
        node->val = val;
        node->right = node->left = NULL;
    }


    /* Consider what will happen when node is null, you are still trying to access null memory. You need to put else if here to avoid control to fall into this condition if node is null. */
    if(node->val > val) // add "else" here
        node->left = Insert(node->left, val);
    else
        node->right = Insert(node->right, val);
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining , recursion is a bit confusing at the beginning, this condition apply in all the recursive methods? For example, count the number of nodes.